# How to solve the syllogism problem

Tags: logical-deduction

Two statements are given below followed by two conclusions, I and II. You have to consider the statements to be true even if they seem to be at variance from commonly known facts. You have to choose which of the given conclusions, if any, follow(s) only from the given statements.

> Statements: 
> A.    Some horses are domestic animals. 
> B.    Domestic animals
> like human contacts.
>
> Conclusions:
>  I.   Some horses do not like human contacts.
> II.   All those who like human contacts are domestic animals.
>
> a. Only conclusion I follows from the given statements.
>  b. Both
> conclusions I and II follow from the given statements.
>  c. Only
> conclusion II follows from the given statements.
>  d. Neither
> conclusion I nor II follows from the given statements.
> Please suggest venn diagram also.
> Source: APSC CCE Paper 2, 2021 (Assam, India)

Answer (score 3):

The answer would be

> D

Explanation:

> Lets consider the conclusions:
>
> 1. Some horses do not like human contacts - Does not follow
>     - we know that the domestic horses like human contact but don’t know if non-domestic horses do. All horses may like human contact
> 2. All those who like human contacts are domestic animals - Does not follow
>     - just because domestic animals like human contact, doesn’t mean non domestic animals don’t

So with that information the answer is then

> D - neither conclusion follows from the statements